how to modify a linked list by using pointers only
I have a linked list of Option<Box<ListNode>> type, a node of this list contains two properties: value (i32) and next (Option<Box<ListNode>>). I've created a vector of pointers (Vec<&Box<ListNode>>) with the purpose of serving to modify the original list as showed in the following picture:

Note: the resulting list should be: L: 1 -> 2 -> n-1 -> n
This is my code, it needs some fixes but at the moment I need to know if I can modify my linked list by using pointers.
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct ListNode {
  pub val: i32,
  pub next: Option<Box<ListNode>>
}

impl ListNode {
  #[inline]
  pub fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
    ListNode {
      next: None,
      val
    }
  }
}

pub fn delete_duplicates(head: Option<Box<ListNode>>) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
    head.as_ref()?;

    type NodeRef<'a> = &'a Box<ListNode>;
    type OptNodeRef<'a> = Option<NodeRef<'a>>;

    const MAX_NODES: u16 = 300;
    // let mut head = head;
    let mut current: OptNodeRef = head.as_ref();
    let mut node_ref: OptNodeRef = None;
    let mut vec_ref: Vec<NodeRef> = Vec::with_capacity(MAX_NODES as usize);
    let mut counter: u16 = 0;

    while let Some(node) = current {
        if node_ref.is_none() || node_ref.unwrap().val != node.val {
            node_ref = Some(node);
            if counter > 0 { 
                vec_ref.push(node);
            }
            counter = 0;
        } else {
            counter += 1;
        }

        current = node.next.as_ref();
    }
    
    if counter > 0 {
        vec_ref.push(node_ref.unwrap());
    }
    // vec_ref.into_iter().map(|t| t.val).for_each(|e| println!("{:?}", e));

    // my problem starts from here...
    for i in 0..vec_ref.len() - 1 {
        vec_ref[i].next = Some(*vec_ref[i + 1]);
    }

    if let Some(last_node) = vec_ref.last() {
        last_node.next = None;
    }

    if let Some(first_node) = vec_ref.first() {
        Some(**first_node)
    } else {
        None
    }
}


how to get it? I've tried some things but I always get an error related to borrow, move, mismatch errors. It seems simple to modify "next" property but I'm out of ideas.

Please show your current code. Even if non-working, it gives us a start point.

Why is the note in disagreement with your picture? Change either to match the other!

& is a shared reference, not a pointer, you can't use them to mutate something without interior mutability.

Also if you want to implement linked lists it's strongly recommended to read Rust with Too Many Linked Lists.

I've added my code to review

"I've added my code to review" - Please note, that stack overflow is not a place to ask for a code review. You might find codereview on stackexchange or Rust users forum a better place for that.

ListNode struct added

Ah, yea, thought as much. With that definition it's an impossible task.

What the others are saying is: Linked Lists in Rust are hard, because they are a very bad data structure for the borrow checker. Implementing them is pretty much impossible without using unsafe and raw pointers. It's all explained in this post, which @cafce25 already linked. Read this first before continuing to attempt this.

Also, which others also pointed out, you seem to have a misunderstanding of pointers vs references. You might want to read the respective sections in the Rust book again. References are for borrowing, which is pretty much useless for linked lists. Borrowing happens at compile time, not at runtime. On the other hand, pointers cannot be checked by the borrow checker and must therefore be used in an unsafe block. That's why linked lists are hard in Rust.

It's not clear to me whether you want to remove duplicates (like your code suggests), or whether you want to keep the first two and last two elements only, and remove anything in between (like the first part of the question suggests), which is probably why my answer is getting downvoted. Could you please clarify?

I wish to delete duplicates, my picture was illustrative only.

With the added code this is now a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54510346/cannot-borrow-as-mutable-more-than-once-error-in-a-loop

Here is my thought, first, basically avoid using linked list in Rust, rust is just not a good language for using linked list because the ownershipe model.
second, if you want a link list I think you should tried to avoid messing with reference too much. Pointer is already hard to think about, let alone pointer comply with ownership rule.
think about who own the piece of data.
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct ListNode {
    pub val: i32,
    pub next: Option<Box<ListNode>>,
}

impl ListNode {
    #[inline]
    pub fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
        ListNode { next: None, val }
    }

    /// Functions I added for testing
    /// 
    /// Push an element to the end of the list
    pub fn push(&mut self, val: i32) {
        let mut current: &mut ListNode = self;
        while current.next.is_some() {
            current = current.next.as_mut().unwrap();
        }
        current.next = Some(Box::new(ListNode { val, next: None }));
    }
    /// Print Out the list
    pub fn print(&self) {
        print!("[{:>3?}]", self.val);
        let mut current: &ListNode = self;
        while current.next.is_some() {
            current = current.next.as_ref().unwrap();
            print!(" -> [{:>3?}]", current.val);
        }

        println!("");
    }
}

/// I refactored the whole function
pub fn delete_duplicates(head: Option<Box<ListNode>>) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
    // The head of the list, if there aren't a list, return None
    let mut head: Box<ListNode> = head?;
    let mut current: Option<Box<ListNode>> = head.next.take();
    let mut tail: &mut Box<ListNode> = &mut head;

    // we TAKE the second element as the current node
    //
    // you can think of it as
    //
    //               |- tail
    //               v
    // head : () -> [first val]
    //
    // current: () -> [second val] -> [thrid val] -> ...
    //

    // Then we keep dequeuing the current
    // when current is None, we know the list ended
    while let Some(mut c) = current {
        //
        //                                     | tail
        //                                     v
        //  head : () -> [1] -> [2] -> ... -> [4]
        //  c    : () -> [5] -> [6]-> ...
        //
        // TAKE out the next node as the next current
        current = c.next.take();
        //
        //                                        | tail
        //                                        v
        //  head    : () -> [1] -> [2] -> ... -> [4]
        //  c       : () -> [5]
        //  current : () -> [6] -> [7]-> ...
        //
        // if the c.val is not equal to the last list, we push it to the end of the list
        if c.val != tail.val {
            tail.next = Some(c);
            tail = tail.next.as_mut().unwrap();
            //
            //                                               | tail
            //                                               v
            //  head    : () -> [1] -> [2] -> ... -> [4] -> [5]
        }
    }

    Some(head)
}
fn main() {
    let mut list: ListNode = ListNode::new(1);
    list.push(2);
    list.push(2);
    list.push(3);
    list.push(4);
    list.print();
    let new_list: Box<ListNode> = delete_duplicates(Some(Box::new(list))).unwrap();
    new_list.print();
}

output
[  1] -> [  2] -> [  2] -> [  3] -> [  4]
[  1] -> [  2] -> [  3] -> [  4]

that way, head own the whole list, and tail handle the mutation of the list. which comply with the ownership rule, one owner, and only one mutable reference.
Performance
performance is way faster if the function take reference instead of the the whole list like Andrea Corbellini's solution
use std::io::Write;

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct ListNode {
    pub val: i32,
    pub next: Option<Box<ListNode>>,
}

impl ListNode {
    #[inline]
    pub fn new(val: i32) -> Self {
        ListNode { next: None, val }
    }

    /// Functions I added for testing
    ///
    /// Push an element to the end of the list
    pub fn push(&mut self, val: i32) {
        let mut current: &mut ListNode = self;
        while current.next.is_some() {
            current = current.next.as_mut().unwrap();
        }
        current.next = Some(Box::new(ListNode { val, next: None }));
    }
    /// Print Out the list
    pub fn print(&self) {
        print!("[{:>3?}]", self.val);
        let mut current: &ListNode = self;
        while current.next.is_some() {
            current = current.next.as_ref().unwrap();
            print!(" -> [{:>3?}]", current.val);
        }

        println!("");
    }
}

/// I refactored the whole function
pub fn delete_duplicates(head: Option<Box<ListNode>>) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
    // The head of the list, if there aren't a list, return None
    let mut head: Box<ListNode> = head?;
    let mut current: Option<Box<ListNode>> = head.next.take();
    let mut tail: &mut Box<ListNode> = &mut head;

    // we TAKE the second element as the current node
    //
    // you can think of it as
    //
    //               |- tail
    //               v
    // head : () -> [first val]
    //
    // current: () -> [second val] -> [thrid val] -> ...
    //

    // Then we keep dequeuing the current
    // when current is None, we know the list ended
    while let Some(mut c) = current {
        //
        //                                     | tail
        //                                     v
        //  head : () -> [1] -> [2] -> ... -> [4]
        //  c    : () -> [5] -> [6]-> ...
        //
        // TAKE out the next node as the next current
        current = c.next.take();
        //
        //                                        | tail
        //                                        v
        //  head    : () -> [1] -> [2] -> ... -> [4]
        //  c       : () -> [5]
        //  current : () -> [6] -> [7]-> ...
        //
        // if the c.val is not equal to the last list, we push it to the end of the list
        if c.val != tail.val {
            tail.next = Some(c);
            tail = tail.next.as_mut().unwrap();
            //
            //                                               | tail
            //                                               v
            //  head    : () -> [1] -> [2] -> ... -> [4] -> [5]
        }
    }

    Some(head)
}

pub fn delete_duplicates_2(head: Option<Box<ListNode>>) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
    // take ownership of the head, and we will manipulate this directly.
    let mut current = head;
    // Mutable reference to 'current' node. We use 'as_mut' and 'and_then' to traverse and modify the list in place
    let mut current_ref = current.as_mut();

    while let Some(curr_node) = current_ref {
        // check if the next node is a duplicate
        while curr_node
            .next
            .as_ref()
            .map_or(false, |next_node| next_node.val == curr_node.val)
        {
            //skip the duplicate
            curr_node.next = curr_node.next.as_mut().unwrap().next.take();
        }
        // Move to the next node
        current_ref = curr_node.next.as_mut();
    }
    current
}

pub fn delete_duplicates_3(head: &mut Option<Box<ListNode>>) {
    // Make sure that `node` is `Option<&mut Box<ListNode>>`, to
    // avoid taking ownership of nodes after the head (which would
    // not be allowed by Rust)
    let mut node = head.as_mut();

    while let Some(this) = node {
        // Loop through every node that shares the same value as `this`
        loop {
            if let Some(ref mut next) = this.next {
                if this.val == next.val {
                    // `this` and `next` have the same value.
                    // Connect `this` to `next.next`, so that the
                    // list changes from:
                    //
                    //   ... -> this -> next -> next.next -> ...
                    //
                    // to:
                    //
                    //   ... -> this -> next.next -> ...
                    //
                    // The use of `take()` ensures that `next.next`
                    // is replaced with `None` (this avoids taking
                    // multiple ownerships).
                    this.next = next.next.take();
                    continue;
                }
            }
            // Either there's no next node, or the next node has a
            // different value than `this`
            break;
        }
        node = this.next.as_mut();
    }
}

fn delete_duplicates_4(head: &mut Option<Box<ListNode>>) {
    if head.is_none() {
        return;
    }
    let mut head = head.as_mut().unwrap();

    while let Some(ref n) = head.next {
        if head.val == n.val {
            head.next = head.next.take().unwrap().next;
        } else {
            head = head.next.as_mut().unwrap();
        }
    }
}

fn make_list(len: usize) -> ListNode {
    let mut a = 1;
    let mut b = 1;
    let mut list = ListNode::new(a);

    for _ in 0..len {
        let t = b;
        b = (a + b) % 10;
        a = t;
        list.push(a);
    }

    list
}

fn bench(len: usize) {
    let list = make_list(len);

    let N = 2048;

    println!("Bench Testing n = {}", len);
    {
        print!("    running delete_duplicates   . . . ");
        std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
        let mut dt = 0;
        for _ in 0..N {
            let list = Some(Box::new(list.clone()));
            let t0 = std::time::Instant::now();
            let _ = delete_duplicates(list).unwrap();
            dt += t0.elapsed().as_micros();
        }
        println!("{:>8}us", (dt as f64) / (N as f64));
    }
    {
        print!("    running delete_duplicates_2 . . . ");
        std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
        let mut dt = 0;
        for _ in 0..N {
            let list = Some(Box::new(list.clone()));
            let t0 = std::time::Instant::now();
            let _ = delete_duplicates_2(list).unwrap();
            dt += t0.elapsed().as_micros();
        }
        println!("{:>8}us", (dt as f64) / (N as f64));
    }
    {
        print!("    running delete_duplicates_3 . . . ");
        std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
        let mut dt = 0;
        for _ in 0..N {
            let mut list = Some(Box::new(list.clone()));
            let t0 = std::time::Instant::now();
            let _ = delete_duplicates_3(&mut list);
            dt += t0.elapsed().as_micros();
        }
        println!("{:>8}us", (dt as f64) / (N as f64));
    }
    {
        print!("    running delete_duplicates_3 . . . ");
        std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
        let mut dt = 0;
        for _ in 0..N {
            let mut list = Some(Box::new(list.clone()));
            let t0 = std::time::Instant::now();
            let _ = delete_duplicates_4(&mut list);
            dt += t0.elapsed().as_micros();
        }
        println!("{:>8}us", (dt as f64) / (N as f64));
    }
}

fn main() {
    for i in 5..=11 {
        bench(1 << i);
    }
}

Output
Bench Testing n = 32
    running delete_duplicates   . . . 2.052734375us
    running delete_duplicates_2 . . . 2.16943359375us
    running delete_duplicates_3 . . . 0.0556640625us 
    running delete_duplicates_4 . . . 0.1826171875us
Bench Testing n = 64
    running delete_duplicates   . . . 4.1171875us
    running delete_duplicates_2 . . . 5.03515625us
    running delete_duplicates_3 . . . 0.33154296875us
    running delete_duplicates_4 . . . 0.06396484375us
Bench Testing n = 128
    running delete_duplicates   . . . 8.5419921875us
    running delete_duplicates_2 . . . 8.87158203125us
    running delete_duplicates_3 . . . 1.1669921875us
    running delete_duplicates_4 . . . 1.193359375us
Bench Testing n = 256
    running delete_duplicates   . . . 18.2841796875us
    running delete_duplicates_2 . . . 20.169921875us
    running delete_duplicates_3 . . . 2.74169921875us
    running delete_duplicates_4 . . . 2.35791015625us
Bench Testing n = 512
    running delete_duplicates   . . . 37.2880859375us
    running delete_duplicates_2 . . . 36.0595703125us
    running delete_duplicates_3 . . . 5.30224609375us
    running delete_duplicates_4 . . . 5.31103515625us
Bench Testing n = 1024
    running delete_duplicates   . . . 66.796875us
    running delete_duplicates_2 . . . 69.91552734375us
    running delete_duplicates_3 . . . 9.84814453125us
    running delete_duplicates_4 . . . 10.646484375us
Bench Testing n = 2048
    running delete_duplicates   . . . 133.638671875us
    running delete_duplicates_2 . . . 143.2666015625us
    running delete_duplicates_3 . . . 20.03955078125us
    running delete_duplicates_4 . . . 20.87939453125us


Great job @啊鹿Dizzyi. Your code is easy to understand and the testing is valuable. At least I know now I must take care when handle pointers with linked lists.

The first error message you get is this (in Rust 1.80):
error[E0594]: cannot assign to data in an index of `Vec<&Box<ListNode>>`
  --> src/main.rs:51:9
   |
51 |         vec_ref[i].next = Some(*vec_ref[i + 1]);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot assign
   |
   = help: trait `IndexMut` is required to modify indexed content, but it is not implemented for `Vec<&Box<ListNode>>`

The error message here is a bit obscure, but in essence it occurs because you're trying to change an item in the Vec, however the items are behind a & reference, so they're not mutable. You need to change the type from Vec<&Box<ListNode>> to Vec<&mut Box<ListNode>>.
However doing so starts a series of other problems down the road, which are caused by the fact that you would be holding multiple mutable references to the same objects, which is not allowed in safe Rust. You could get around that by using unsafe Rust and mutable pointers instead of mutable references, but in your particular case I think there's a better alternative.
If your intent is to remove duplicates that appear next to each other, then I think your code could be greatly simplified. In particular, you don't need the additional Vec to keep track of the de-duplicated nodes: you can just modify the linked list in place, like this:
pub fn delete_duplicates(head: &mut Option<Box<ListNode>>) {
    // Make sure that `node` is `Option<&mut Box<ListNode>>`, to
    // avoid taking ownership of nodes after the head (which would
    // not be allowed by Rust)
    let mut node = head.as_mut();

    while let Some(this) = node {
        // Loop through every node that shares the same value as `this`
        loop {
            if let Some(ref mut next) = this.next {
                if this.val == next.val {
                    // `this` and `next` have the same value.
                    // Connect `this` to `next.next`, so that the
                    // list changes from:
                    //
                    //   ... -> this -> next -> next.next -> ...
                    //
                    // to:
                    //
                    //   ... -> this -> next.next -> ...
                    //
                    // The use of `take()` ensures that `next.next`
                    // is replaced with `None` (this avoids taking
                    // multiple ownerships).
                    this.next = next.next.take();
                    continue;
                }
            }
            // Either there's no next node, or the next node has a
            // different value than `this`
            break;
        }
        node = this.next.as_mut();
    }
}

Link to Playground

It seems a valid suggestion, however you are changing the defintion of original function which is not desired. I don't understand why someone downvoted it, I don't like when it occurs without any feedbacks.

If you want the function to take and return a Option<Box<ListNode>> (instead of taking a &mut Option<Box<ListNode>>), that's a trivial change. Using &mut has the advantage that it makes the function work in more circumstances
